# How do I construct confidence intervals involving out of bounds values from the prob scale to the logit scale and backtransform to the prob scale?

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, data-transformation

I am trying to figure out how to construct confidence intervals with observations' outcome values that were out of bounds on the probability scale (≤0 and ≥1).

For individual observations, I get probabilities outside [0,1] because I am using SuperLearner with several algorithms. SuperLearner just weights the algorithms' predictions by how much they reduce the algorithms' loss functions most. Averaging those individual observations never produces a point estimate out of bounds, but the larger my intervention gets, the larger the standard error gets, so for some interventions, the confidence interval estimates fall outside [0,1]. The estimator I am using is called the incremental propensity score estimator. See Kennedy 2019.

I think I should transform the distribution to another scale and back-transform so that the original point estimates are retained and the confidence intervals are in bounds. However because some individuals' outcome values are ≤0 and ≥1, I can't logit transform because NaNs are produced.

Does anyone know a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Why do you get probabilities outside $[0,1]$? We really need some context to give help here!

Comment: For individual observations, I get probabilities outside [0,1] because I am using SuperLearner with several algorithms. SuperLearner just weights the algorithms predictions by how much they reduce the algorithms loss function most. Averaging those individual observations never produces a point estimate out of bounds, but the larger my intervention gets, the larger the standard error gets, so for some interventions, the confidence interval estimates fall outside [0,1]. The estimator I am using is called the incremental propensity score estimator. See Kennedy 2019.

Comment: Please add this new info to the post as an edit!